# Set The Value of Input Field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set the value of a text input field when someone clicks anchor/button. Right now I have this:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#text-add").click(function(){
    $("#domain-pick").val("test");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<a id="text-add" href="javascript:void(0);">Click Here</a>

<input type="text" name="text-field" id="domain-pick">
```

I got it working in Jsfiddle, but it will not work on my wordpress site!

Comment: `$("text-add")` `<-` I doubt this works in jsFiddle.

Comment: replace 'text-add' with  '#text-add'

Comment: That was a typo, it didn't work with #text-add either

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbbottam/2KLUX/).

Note:

- You don't need to wrap the function in `document.ready` if you are
  `script` appears after the markup.
- Please avoid inline **javascript**, like `javascript:void(0);`

Markup:

```
<a id="text-add" href="#">Click Here</a>
<input type="text" name="text-field" id="domain-pick">
```

JS:

```
$("#text-add").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#domain-pick").val("test");
});
```

Comment: Its working in Jsfiddle, but not my site. It doesn't make any sense, I added everything correctly